# Type 1 Error, Type 2 Error Exercise

Tags: statistics

> Five trials $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_5$ of a Bernoulli experiment were conducted to test $H_o : p = \frac12$, against $H_a : p = \frac34$ The null hypothesis $H_o$ will be rejected if the $\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i = 5$. Find the probability of Type I and Type II errors.

Answer: Type I: $0.03125$, Type II: $0.763$.

The Type I error looks like it's $\left(\frac12\right)^5$, but I don't understand why...
Then I can't figure out how to solve the type II error.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: What is the question? What problem are you dealing with?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer look like this $$P\left(\sum {X_{i}}=5|p=\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ i.e. Type I error means that you reject null while it is true. So you should find the probability that the rejection requirement is satisfied in the case $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (i.e. the initial hypo is true).
You get 5 in Bernoulli trials when you have 5 lucks in 5 experiments. Its prob is $$P\left(\sum {X_{i}}=5|p\right)=p^{5}$$
For our case it will be $(1/2)^5$.

For Type II error, you'll have $$P\left(\sum {X_{i}}<5|p=\frac{3}{4}\right)$$ (so the type II error is "not rejecting" $H_{0}$, when $H_{1}$ is true.)
We can go in other direction 
$$P\left(\sum {X_{i}}<5|p=\frac{3}{4}\right)=1-P\left(\sum {X_{i}}=5|p=\frac{3}{4}\right)=1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^5$$.